# Kibana + Logstash + Elastic group exceptions by stacktrace

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

For now I have logstashed installed and I can see all [ERROR] messages and stacktraces in Kibana.

However I would like to group my exceptions by its stacktraces to see only unique exceptions. For example, I have 2 different NullPointerException throwned from different classes/lines of codes and 1 IllegalArgumentException. This exceptions repeats in logs multiple times, and I can see all occurrence in Kibana.

What I would like to see, something similar to this

1. NullPointerException + trace - thwwn 78 times.
2. Another NullPointerException + trace - thrown 112 times.
3. IllegalArgumentException + trace - thrown 991 times.

This is how fabric.io works for mobile crashes/issues. It is possible to do something similar ?

Comment: If you have a field that you want to aggregate on (the exception name and trace in your example), you can use the "data table" visualization to show you a count of each.

Comment: I don't know the "future" stacktraces or exception names. I just want to see "unique" exceptions. Counting is optional

Comment: If you can parse it into a field (like with logstash's grok{}), you can show the unique ones with an aggregation in a visualization as mentioned above.

Comment: @Anton did you find a solution for this? If so please answer your own question or accept the one below, if that one works.

Answer (score 1):

The way we did this was to set up a data table visualisation with a Terms query on the field containing the stacktrace. Mind you however to aggregate on the .raw version of your field otherwise you will see the analysed (e.g. split) version of the stacktraces which is not what you want.

The second problem I came across is that there is a maximum size of the text to be used for the terms filter (unfortunately I can't find the docs for that). Anything larger than that is simply omitted from the aggregation. I worked around that by creating an additional field containing the first 200 characters of the stacktrace which I then use to aggregate on.

```
    grok {
        match => [ "exceptionTxt","(?<exceptionTxtShort>^.{0,200})"]
    }
```

It's not perfect but it does the trick for us. If anyone knows the link to the docs and/or how to properly work around this limitation please comment.

Comment: Aren't you risking leaving out important stack trace information? 200 characters isn't that much for a stack trace.. And even though they have the first 200 chars the next ones can easily differ and therefore your "counts" may not be counting the same exception.

Comment: @badaboomskey Of course you are right. This is just a hack / workaround because I did not know how to properly set the maximum length for the term filter.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I would STRONGLY not follow your suggestion. I know it is from 2015 (and therefore easy to critisize today..), but today that is not the way to do it. Also - I don't know if it was a possibility in 2015 (I haven't used Grafana for that long) - today you would just use .keyword to get an overview of each exception and use fx exception.stacktrace to get the trace shown (not cut it off). If it should cut off and not show fx exceptions with stacktraces longer than fx 200 chars, then go configure/set the "ignore_above" parameter. Don't cut off stacktraces ;)